# CoreMotion wont give me roll, pitch and yaw

Tags: objective-c, accelerometer, core-motion, pitch, cmmotionmanager

sBefore `UIAccelerometer` was deprecated from iOS I used the data from `x`, `y` and `z` from this class to calculate pitch, roll and yaw. I also had to do some filtering, but now I see that with the `CoreMotion` library I can get these data from the [`CMAttitude` class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and would really like to use these properties, but somehow I fail to do so.

Now, what I have done is to instantiate

```
CMMotionManager *motionManager;
CMDeviceMotion  *deviceMotion;
CMAttitude      *attitude;
...
deviceMotion    = motionManager.deviceMotion;
attitude        = deviceMotion.attitude;

motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.065; // 65ms
[motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];
```

I am able to read x,y and z from `motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration.<x,y or z>` but trying to read from `attitude.<roll,pitch,yaw>`  gives me 0.

```
NSLog(@"Roll: %f", attitude.roll); // = 0
```

I read out the values in a method triggered by a continous timer each 100ms.

Any ideas on what I`m missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `deviceMotion.attitude` you have to call `[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates]`.

`startAccelerometerUpdates` provides accelerometer data only like `startGyroUpdates` will give you `gyroData`. Note that device motion data is more than just accelerometer and gyro data as both of them will be combined (sensor fusion) to achieve more precision.

Comment: Thank you sir, that was it. Didn't know that they combined data from the two to achieve this.